# ffmpeg doesn't run unless output is redirected in java

Tags: java, ffmpeg

I'm currently running a ffmpeg process in java using:

```
Process ffmpeg = new ProcessBuilder("ffmpeg", ...).start();
ffmpeg.waitFor();
```

The issue is this process never terminates. However, if I do:

```
ProcessBuilder ffmpeg = new ProcessBuilder("ffmpeg", ...);
ffmpeg.redirectErrorStream(true).redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
ffmpeg.start().waitFor();
```

The process runs fine.

Does anyone know why this might happen? It seems extremely weird that a process won't proceed unless I read its output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's perfectly normal. There's a limited sized output buffer that needs to be read (or redirected to a bitbucket).

It's also one of the most common pitfalls when people start using `ProcessBuilder` and don't read the documentation first ;)